# Use python to create a space between adjacent characters

Tags: python

I have a web scraper that grabs the content of a page and writes to a csv file.

The result will be fed into another script that takes the contents of a row index and uses that as an aws profile name.

For some of the rows the names are run together:

```
company-govcloud-ab-mc-nonprod(MC Non Prod)
company-govcloud-ab-mc-admin-prod(MC Prod Admin)
company-govcloud-ab-mc-prod(MC Prod)
```

I want to put a space in between the profile name and the words in parenthesis. I am not able to change the contents of the page that I am scraping.

How can I separate:

```
company-govcloud-ab-mc-prod(MC Prod)
So that the result reads:
company-govcloud-ab-mc-prod (MC Prod)
```

In my code I tried using a replace to insert the space, but it did not work:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
auth = get_login()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, features="html.parser")
table = soup.find('div',{'id':'content'})
rows = []
for table_row in table.find_all('tr'):
    columns = table_row.find_all('td')
    output_row = []
    for column in columns:
        output_row.append(column.text.strip())
        output_row = output_row.replace('d(','d (')    
    rows.append(output_row)
```

How can I insert a space between the profile name and the first parenthesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in your call to `append`:

```
column.text.strip().replace('(', ' (')
```

...and remove `output_row = output_row.replace('d(','d (')`, because lists don't have a `replace` method.